# How to validate edittext-mask and how to validate AutoCompleteTextview?

Tags: android

1) How to validate edittext-mask?
Am using this library.

> compile 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'

When am trying to validate the edittext it is not validating.Please look on to my code,

```
if (rp_ipET.getText().toString().length()<1) { rp_ipET.setError("Please select or enter a machine IP"); return; }
```

2) AutoCompleteTextview is validating.But while am setting the error message is not clearing after i entered something on autocompletetextview.

```
 if (machineNameAT.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                machineNameAT.setError("Please select or enter a machine name");
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is in [MaskedEditText](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask) , the working will be like this

For example +7 (999) 705 - 56 -71 is the input

If you use `getText()`  it will return `+7 (999) 705 - 56 -71`

If you use `getRawText()` it will return `9997055671`

The problem may be with un-wanted spaces in your string while your taking. so try to trim() the text and use it.

I.e like this

```
  if (rp_ipET.getRawText().toString().trim().length()<1) 
   {
     rp_ipET.setError("Please select or enter a machine IP");
     return;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace like this,it is worked for me.

1)

```
 if (machineNameAT.getText().toString().trim().length()<1) {
                    machineNameAT.setError("Please select or enter a machine name");
                    return;
                }
```

2)

```
if (rp_ipET.getRawText().toString().trim().length()<1) {
                    rp_ipET.setError("Please select or enter a machine IP");
                    return;
                }
```